# Fetch data from Rally in Excel Macro using vb script

Tags: rally

I want to get data like Workspace,Projects,Sub Projects,Releases etc from Rally in excel Macro

I am able to connect to Rally but I Need code in VB scripts to get the Workspacelist and selecting a workspace project list, upon selecting a project sub project and then release.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excel add-in that makes it very easy to query data from Rally and pull it into sheets in excel.  Are you using that?  Once the data is in there it should be straightforward to manipulate in VB.  We don't have any existing tools for doing this natively in VB though.